# ElastiCache for Redis: set key value hanging indefinitely in redis-cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis, amazon-elasticache

I'm trying to save a key value pair in Amazon ElastiCache for Redis but the `set` command is getting stuck.

I first do:

`redis-cli -h ${aws-elasticache-cluster-url} -p 6739`

And then:

`aws-elasticache-cluster-url:6739> set mykey "myvalue"`

The command gets stuck here & doesn't indicate success nor failure.

If it works correctly, the command should print "OK".

What's wrong?

The steps I tried are from this document
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/GettingStarted.ConnectToCacheNode.html

Comment: Is your `aws-elasticache-cluster-url` definitely correct?

Comment: Also - are you using the primary endpoint if you have a cluster?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary It's because TLS in elasticache is enabled. I've fixed by adding enabling ssl and attach auth token to the command and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out my elasticache cluster is setup with TLS mode. That's why it's unable to run get/set in redis. Enabling ssl to the command and code will help to run with get/set. Hope this help to anyone having the same issue.

https://redis.io/topics/rediscli

https://redis.io/topics/encryption